# docker-compose failed to build service

Tags: docker

I am working with oatpp web framework and integrated mongodb module and clone example-mongodb demo project a basic CRUD application with oatpp and mongodb with swagger integrated.I am trying to run docker-compose up from terminal open in my project directory but getting error like below:

```
$example-mongodb$docker-compose up
Building example-service
Step 1/11 : FROM lganzzzo/alpine-mongocxx:latest
 ---> a39b08adb312
Step 2/11 : ADD src/ /service/src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ffeef3ce297b
Step 3/11 : ADD utility/ /service/utility/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cb8dfbf0a2bf
Step 4/11 : ADD CMakeLists.txt /service/CMakeLists.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 83e98f4a776d
Step 5/11 : WORKDIR /service/utility
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 50ea5d092947
Step 6/11 : RUN ./install-oatpp-modules.sh Release
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2e6133bd640b
Step 7/11 : WORKDIR /service/build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 498c1ccea65d
Step 8/11 : RUN cmake ..
 ---> Running in d5b368846760
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS=
LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES=
LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS=
LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES=
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:74 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    test/tests.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx

-- Build files have been written to: /service/build
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:74 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: example-mongodb-test

ERROR: Service 'example-service' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cmake ..' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have installed docker and docker-compose already on my local system and all dependency already set up on my local system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added `src` and `utility` folders to your image but you missed add `test` folder into it.By adding test folder, I guess everything will be ok.

`ADD test/ /service/test/`

Comment: Thank you so much that resolved issues but now getting 
ERROR: for examplemongodb_mongodb_1  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

ERROR: for mongodb  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).

Comment: what is your docker-compose?